# Session API validity

Tags: soap-api, session, session-id

We have currently configured Session timeout as 2 hours on the API User Profile. Our Org. is connected to a .net application using these API User credentials. Say connection is established successfully with SF so the session id .net app use is going to be valid for 2 hours though there is no activity on it. 
1. Is my understanding correct?
2. .net App(basically a tool) if closed after connecting it with SF and opened it within 2 hours time frame then can the same session id be used?
Can someone please clarify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For both of your questions the answer is Yes. But the time frame is maintained under the `Session Settings` in Setup.

> As per docs:
>
> The session timeout for an access token can be configured in
>   Salesforce from Setup by entering Session Settings in the Quick Find
>   box, then selecting Session Settings.

[image]

In Session Setting you can maintain all the configuration related to Session maintenance. But if any user change it at profile level then it will override this default value.

[Understanding the OAuth Refresh Token Process](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/intro_understanding_refresh_token_oauth.htm)

Comment: You can assign Session Length values to individual profiles, and it will override the default org settings.

Comment: Thanks @Tushar and sfdcfox. Just one last question, is there any harm if I increase the session time out value to 12 or 24 hours?

Comment: @Kanikala There is no harm.you can do that